# Communicating between ROS and non-ROS (LabView) via TCP/IP

Tags: ros, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
In our project we're using ROS running on a fit-pc for high-level and NI-sRIO and other NI components for low-level. We need to pass some signals between high-level and low-level.

LabView can read signals from an IP-address, but I can't figure out how to use ROS to simply dump data to a specific port. Can anyone help on this?

As far as I understand, the ROSTCP simply allows connecting different CPUs running ROS very easily, but is not meant for communicating between ROS and non-ROS hardware via TCP/IP.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9554/communicating-between-ros-and-non-ros-(labview)-via-tcp/ip/) by [lifesayko](https://answers.ros.org/users/346/lifesayko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROSTCP is not intended to be used outside of the ROS architecture, as far as I know.  So, I think that you would have to implement some minimum bit of a ROS client library in order to use ROS with labview.  You probably want to read up on a few things:

- [Implementing Client Libraries](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Implementing%20Client%20Libraries) - a good overview of what a client library MUST and SHOULD do in order to operate.
- [ROS Technical Overiew](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Technical%20Overview) - A concept of operations for ROS
- [TCPROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/TCPROS) - The transport layer for messages and services in ROS.

You may also be able to take a look at the Orocos toolchain code to get an idea of how to build a "relay" node of sorts.

I have briefly investigated actually implementing some portion of a client library on LabVIEW, but it seemed that it would be a significant undertaking with little actual gain.  If you are primarily interested in creating GUIs and control panels, most of that is successfully handled in ROS already, or easily implemented in something like QT or MatPlotLib.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At [CWRU](http://mobilerobots.case.edu), we also use NI CompactRIOs for low-level control and standard x86 PCs for higher-level processing. The x86 computers run Ubuntu and ROS and are networked to the NI cRIOs.

What we did to facilitate communication between components was to write a simple UDP protocol for the interaction between the cRIO and ROS PC instead of attempting to implement a ROSTCP client on the cRIO side. In this case, all we needed to do is write a listener program on the ROS PC that translated our protocol into ROS messages - and since it's on the x86 PC, we were able to use the existing roscpp and rospy libraries.

For host PC side examples, check out [crio_receiver.cpp](https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg/blob/master/cwru_semi_stable/cwru_base/src/crio_receiver.cpp) (latest, but most complex listener node) and [pose_broadcaster.py](https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg/blob/master/cwru_semi_stable/cwru_base/src/pose_broadcaster.py) (older, but simpler Python node). These nodes listen to UDP packets from the robot's cRIO and extract information to fill a [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) with.
There is also the [twist_receiver.py](https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru-ros-pkg/blob/master/cwru_semi_stable/cwru_base/src/twist_receiver.py) that takes Twist messages and outputs UDP commands containing speed and spin rate to the cRIO.

For the cRIO side, you should be able to find some examples of packing and sending UDP (or TCP if you prefer) packets from LabView. We actually used C on the cRIO using the GNU toolchain available on NI's website, but, due to the unknown state of the copyright on some of the files, our cRIO code is not open-source and cannot be redistributed.

Hope that helps. I'd be happy to elaborate more on any of this if you have specific questions.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-28**:
Ha... O we love CompactRIOs alright... . Nice hardware - terrible software is my experience, which is why we switched to C on the cRIO from LabView in the first place :-). There's a way longer rant in there, but I'll spare ROS Answers. What would you find useful on a wiki page?

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-03-27**:
I forgot that you Case Western guys love the CompactRIOs.  Have you created a ROS wiki page for this?  I'm sure a lot of institutions would be very interested in this capability.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, we support both ROS and LabVIEW on our mobile products, so it's been occasionally convenient to have the two chat to each other. We've adopted an approach pretty similar to what lifesayko and Eric Perko are doing. In Python, though, packing up a message that LabVIEW's "Unflatten From String" block will recognize is really easy. This is really all there is to it:

```
class LabviewProxy:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('labview_proxy')

        self.ip = rospy.get_param('~ip', '')
        self.port = rospy.get_param('~port', 12345)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                              socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        rospy.Subscriber("cmd_vel", Twist, self.cmd_vel_handler)
        rospy.spin()

  def cmd_vel_handler(self, data):
        msg = struct.pack('!dd', data.linear.x, data.angular.z)
        self.sock.sendto(msg, (self.ip, self.port))
```

You can find the syntax for Python's struct.pack and struct.unpack format strings in the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html). From there, it's relatively simple to put together the reverse: listening on a socket and publishing messages from LabVIEW out to ROS.

In the longer run, it would be helpful to have support for the ROS messaging stack in LabVIEW itself (VIs generated from message definitions, etc), but this is a sufficient stopgap in the short term.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2011-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2011-04-15**:
It would be possible to generate them from within LabVIEW using VI Scripting: http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209110

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2011-04-15**:
Eric: Not that I'm aware of. Having looked into a bit further, I'm not even sure how one would go about developing it---the VIs are proprietary binary files, and it doesn't look like there's been much work done on documenting them.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-14**:
Are there actually any open-source tools for generating a VI?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. Clearpath has launched a LabVIEW ROS toolkit that links LabVIEW systems to ROS-based algorithms and hardware drivers.

ROS Toolkit for LabVIEW
http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/210716

---

Originally posted by [gtr902](https://answers.ros.org/users/2460/gtr902/) with karma: 71 on 2012-05-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As some people (ourselves included) have pointed out, Clearpath has released a beta of a toolkit for connecting ROS & LabVIEW. It's available [here](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/210716). There's also a tutorial which should be reformatted for NI's site soon - prerelease version is [here](http://files.clearpathrobotics.com/ROS Toolkit Example.pdf).

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4